# QUAD After a New Line Inside ITEMIZE Doesn't Work

Tags: indentation, itemize

I'm using `quad` inside `itemize`. In detail,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1a\\Item 1b
\item Item 2\\\quad Subitem 2a\\\quad Subitem 2b
\item Item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The `quad`s in front of Subitems 2a and 2b don't work. Can I activate the `quad`s by force? Thanks.

Comment: As your item text suggests you want to have sub-items inside your items, why not just nesting several `itemize` or `enumerate` environments? Also have a look at the [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package which makes customizing indentation and item labels easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\quad` is equivalent to `\hspace{1em}`. However, `\hspace`s at the start of a line is gobbled. If you want to force it, you need to use `\hspace*{1em}`. Below I define `\Quad` to be exactly that.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Quad}{\hspace*{1em}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Item 1a \\ Item 1b
  \item Item 2 \\ \quad Subitem 2a \\ \quad Subitem 2b
  \item Item 3
\end{itemize}

\hrulefill

\begin{itemize}
  \item Item 1a \\ Item 1b
  \item Item 2 \\ \Quad Subitem 2a \\ \Quad Subitem 2b
  \item Item 3
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```